# click button => prevent onclick & show modal, click yes => callback the onclick function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page with multiple input That All look like the below. 
And I want to display a modal before executing the onclick. 
The onclick function should be running when the yes button of the modal is clicked.
My problem is that when I click yes, the function executed is always that of the first input. Then I have to execute the function of the clicked button
Many thanks for any help with this.

HTML:

```
<input id="first" class="btn btn-success" type="button" onclick="doFirstFunction()" value="FirstFunction"/><br>
<input id="second" class="btn btn-success" type="button" onclick="doSecondFunction()" value="SecondFunction"/><br>
<input id="third" class="btn btn-success" type="button" onclick="doThirdFunction()" value="ThirdFunction"/>
```

//Modal

```
<div class="modal fade in" id="confirmationYesNo" aria-hidden="false">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Confirmation</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                Are you sure ?
                <button id="btnYes" type="button" class="btn btn-danger" >Yes</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
    var input = $("input[type=button]");
    var defaultFunctionToCallLater = $("input").prop('onclick');
    console.log("defaultFunctionToCallLater", defaultFunctionToCallLater);
    $("input").prop("onclick", null );
    //$("input").removeProp("onclick");

    input.click(function(e){
            var $target = $(e.target);
            var isThird = (e.target.id == 'third');

    if(!(isThird)){                
      $('#confirmationYesNo').appendTo("body").modal({
      backdrop:'static',keyboard:false}).show();    
        $("#btnYes").click(function(){
            addEventListener('click', defaultFunctionToCallLater);
        });
      }

});

function doFirstFunction(){
    location.href="link1";
};

function doSecondFunction(){
    location.href="link2";

}; 

function doThirdFunction(){
    location.href="link3";
};
```

Comment: Why not have a function callModal with a parameter for which function to call when you click on yes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input id="first" class="btn btn-success" type="button" onclick="modalFunction(1)" value="FirstFunction"/><br>
<input id="second" class="btn btn-success" type="button" onclick="modalFunction(2)" value="SecondFunction"/><br>
<input id="third" class="btn btn-success" type="button" onclick="modalFunction(3)" value="ThirdFunction"/>
```

And here is the JS

```
function openModal(callbackFunc) {
   switch(callbackFunc) {
      case 1:
         $("#btnYes").on('click', doFirstFunction);
         break;
      case 2:
         $("#btnYes").on('click', doSecondFunction);
         break;
      case 3:
         $("#btnYes").on('click', doThirdFunction);
         break;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but to make it clear, I have a lot of input and a, button ... So I'm trying to save the onclick content of the clicked button. And recall this function when yes is clicked PS: I have to bring this change to an existing page where I can not modify the id and the onclick values

Comment: In that case you should modify the code in question to reflect that. I do not see the code for `defaultFunctionToCallLater`. You should start by adding it. Secondly, your code should demonstrate what you mean by saving the onclick content. Are you talking about about the onclick event? If so, you can pass that as a parameter to the subsequent functions you're calling.

Comment: Thank you for your help Pedro Hoehl Carvalho

Answer (score 0):

All youre inputs should call showModal(id) (id = 1; id=2; ...)
The modal function will just show the modal and redirect to your js functions when you press YES

```js
function showModal(id){

(showtheModal)
IF YES IS PRESSED

switch(id){
        case 1:
            doFirstFunction();
            break;
        case 3:
            doSecondFunction();
            break;
        case 3:
            doThirdFunction();
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but to make it clear, I have a lot of input and a, buttons ... So I'm trying to save the onclick content of the clicked button. And recall this function when yes is clicked
PS: I have to bring this change to an existing page where I can not modify the id and the onclick values